# How to store "com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text" in database

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, google-cloud-datastore

So i have been trying to make a blog engine.
I want to insert a  `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text`  variable into the database.

I made a servlet and tried to accept a Text variable is a `request.getParameter()`

The problem is that is gives me an error ~

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Text

This is my code:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res){

    try {
        String action = req.getParameter(Constants.ACTION);

        if(action.equals("add")){
                //The next line gives the error
            Text description = req.getParameter("description"); 
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

So how do i insert a Text variable into the database?
If not by servlets.. is there another method?

Answers in java will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor for the `Text` object takes in a `String`. So you should be able to write:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res){
  try {
    String action = req.getParameter(Constants.ACTION);
    if(action.equals("add")){
      Text description = new Text(req.getParameter("description")); 
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }
}
```

Comment: so this is basically creating a new Text variable and then storing it? or is this parsing it?

Comment: This is just creating a new Text variable that you can then store on an `Entity` using `setUnindexedProperty`: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/PropertyContainer#setUnindexedProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object). Once you've stored it in the entity, you have to actually put the Entity in the datastore.

Comment: `Text` is simply a wrapper around a `String` to distinguish between an indexed property of type 'String' and an unindexed property of type 'Text'.